# Why does Hermione whisper Levicorpus?

Tags: harry-potter, hermione-granger

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* Chapter 26: *Gringotts*, when:

> Harry, Ron, Hermione, and Griphook are trying to get Helga Hufflepuff's cup from Bellatrix's vault.

We see that:

> [Hermione] raised her wand, pointed it at Harry and whispered, '*Levicorpus*.'

However in book 6, when Harry discovers *Levicorpus* in the margins of the Half-Blood Prince's copy of *Advanced Potion Making*, it is written as:

> *Levicorpus (nvbl)*

Where "nvbl" means "non-verbal." Harry proceeds to try out the spell on Ron nonverbally, and it works just fine. In every other instance of its use (e.g. James on Snape in book 5, Harry attempting to use it on Snape in book 6) it is also used non-verbally. It seems to be implied that the spell is *meant* by its inventor only to be used like this; otherwise, why would he have bothered to note "non-verbal" when pretty much any spell (including the Half-Blood Prince's own *Sectumpsempra*) *can* be used silently anyway?

So then why does Hermione (who happens to pick up non-verbal spells incredibly quickly in book 6, and is better at them than either of Harry or Ron) of all people use *Levicorpus* verbally by whispering it? Is there any particular reason for it? Is it even technically supposed to work verbally? If so, why did the Half-Blood Prince explicitly *note* it as non-verbal?

Comment: I think I got an idea, but I forgot exactly what scene was that. Can you remind me why did Hermione lift Harry?

Comment: @Omega Harry couldn't reach Hufflepuff's cup, so Hermione lifted him so that he could take it.

Comment: Ahh... Then nevermind, my idea won't work. Lol. Thank you for reminding me though. Great question btw.

Comment: Regardless of the verbal/non-verbal debate, I am wondering why she had to "whisper" and not just say it loudly...weren't they at this point already crashing through multiplying treasures from the vault? Haven't they given up attempts at stealth at this point?

Answer (score 32):

First, obviously *levicorpus* is not non-verbal-restricted (Hermione did it).

Also, **some spells can be more effective if used non-verbally**. To prove this, we got the following quote:

> For example, the unnamed
>   curse that critically injured Hermione Granger during the Battle of
>   the Department of Mysteries might have been fatal had Antonin Dolohov
>   not been silenced when he used it, according to Hogwarts nurse Poppy
>   Pomfrey
>
> [HP Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Unforgivable_Curses)

This justifies why would Snape write *"nvbl"* next to the spell's name: **he was *confirming* that it is much more effective to use it non-verbally**, thus, whenever he's going to use it in the future, he'll make sure to use it non-verbally, **despite it being possible to use it verbally** (but would, most likely, going to be less-effective).

Thus, Hermione whispering it is now possible.

Now then, the question remains: why would she use it verbally anyway? Well, this depends on **did Hermione know that it would be less effective to use verbally**?

- **If she knew:**

  - Then she used it verbally to purposefully make it less effective. A less effective *levicorpus* implies, very probably, ***less speed***. Clearly, less speed would be better for the situation, because Hermione wouldn't want to "hurt" Harry with the speed - she just wanted to help him by lifting him in a more comfortable manner.
- **If she didn't know:**

  - Then she probably used the spell verbally to "not take Harry by surprise". He just told Hermione he needed to get up - he probably didn't expect to have her casting a spell on him, specially not *levicorpus*. Thus, saying it verbally gives harry a split-second of time to get ready for the hit.

Proof of "split second reaction time"

> *Your adversary has no warning about what kind of magic you are about to perform, **which gives you a split-second advantage**.*
>
> **Hermione Granger**

So if this split-second is valuable enough to be even mentioned, then it certainly is valuable enough for Harry to react accordingly to the spell when Hermione used it on him.

Now then, given how skilled Hermione was with non-verbal spells, it is likely that she knew about such side-effect, thus, the answer to your question: **Hermione used it to lift Harry in a more comfortable manner (instead of brutally lifting him like *levicorpus* normally seems to do).**

Comment: That statement ("Some spells, such as Levicorpus, are easier to perform nonverbally than others") you quoted from HP Wikia is not supported by canon. It's just someone's musings **trying to spin a story around the fact listed in the OP's question**.

Comment: @DVK: Ah, is the *"according to Hogwarts nurse Poppy Pomfrey"* a lie as well? I didn't remember so I thought it was true :(... anyway, in your answer you do mention that *"as we all know, spells always work better (or not worse) when said aloud"* so I guess that my point still stands despite the quoting problem. I'll modify my answer, thanks for telling me.

Comment: The Dolohov thing seems legit. I recall the factoid but not who stated it.

Comment: @DVK: Ah, I forgot about the Dolohov thing. Well, I guess I'll just cut off the non-canon part of the quote then. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, I disagree with your conclusion if the Dolohov thing, sorry. The fact that Hermione was alive was proof that the unnamed curse would have been MORE effective if it was made verbally.

Comment: +1 | "**he was confirming that it is much more effective to use it non-verbally,**" should qualify what counts as more effective. More powerful or more surprising?

Comment: The Dolohov thing doesn't make sense to me either. How do you turn "Would have killed you if he could speak" into "Was more effective because he did not speak"?

Comment: @yamikuronue if you hear it you can block it; see Harry's attempts to use it against Snape and Draco. Perhaps as well, if Dolohov could speak he'd have picked a separate curse?

Comment: @Pureferret I should point out that Harry's attempt to use *levicorpus* against Snape *was* nonverbal. He was halfway through the thought, but Snape was an incredible Legilimens and blocked him before he could finish it.

Answer (score 8):

I don't have canon support, but I have a very simple theory.

Levicorpus is NOT a "nonverbal only spell".

But it IS a spell that seemingly was invented for combat/dueling purposes, as many of Snape's seemed to be.

As such, as a combat spell, you WANT to use it non-verbally, for obvious reasons (to surprise the opponent and not let them prepare or counteract or shield in t
ime).

OTOH, as we all know, spells always work better (or not worse) when said aloud (non-verbal use requires more effort and harder concentration), and therefore Hermione, in the vault, had no need to resort to nonverbalization. (matter of fact, it was better to be verbal so as to NOT surprise Harry).

Answer (score 6):

## Because of their situation

They are:

> Breaking into the second most secure location in the wizarding world, to steal a horcrux of the most powerful dark wizard of their time, which could be guarded by any number of unknown enchantments.

Basically they're under a lot of pressure. As Snape described in HBP,

> "Not all wizards can [cast non-verbal spells], of course; it is a question of concentration and mind power which some" — his gaze lingered maliciously upon Harry once more — "lack."
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, chapter 9*

Hermione would prefer to avoid something that requires extra concentration in a situation like this, so she defaults to using verbal spells. As for why she whispered it instead of speaking it normally, it can be harder for many people to get words out at a normal volume when they're in stressful situations.

Comment: I've upvoted even though I normally wouldn't due to the lack of canonical sources. We like canon excerpts. You can probably read most of many fantasy books just from canon excerpts on this site, please try and include some!

Comment: I'm working on finding that specific excerpt right now...

Comment: Ah cool, all good then, Uplikey from me either way :)

Comment: @Edlothidad - there you go! Thanks for the vote.

Comment: @BenSutton "I'm working on finding that specific excerpt right now..." Given that this question is from *2012* there wasn't a lot of risk of someone ninja-ing you, you could probably have waited until you found the excerpt before posting the answer. But whatever, no need for a lecture is there? +1

Comment: @Au101 it was more the fact that I didn't think I'd be able to find my copy of the ebook to give the direct quote (and didn't necessarily trust a second-hand source) but I felt that the point was still clear without Snape's exact wording so I decided to post it. I happened to find where I saved the ebook and was looking through it when Edlothidad posted his comment. It wasn't due to a fear of ninja-ing, please don't try to presume my motives without knowing the situation

Comment: @BenSutton Sorry if I came across as rude there, or presumptive. What I meant to do, although you're right, I would have done better to be direct, is underline what Edlothiad was saying: a quote or source, where one is available, should always be provided, we're a site that likes canonical sources and you know that may not be obvious to a person who's new to the stack and if you look at old answers there are a lot of unsourced, upvoted answers that would not cut mustard today.

Comment: The one time where we do tend to let other people and/our ourselves get away with it is when the question is new and there's a bit of a race and people put in the answer while they're at work or whatever and then hunt down the quotes when they get home, say. Or put in the answer and quotes, hit post, and then spend time editing in the page numbers, the chapter titles etc. etc. That's when people might get away with it, but otherwise an answer without quotes is unlikely to get upvotes and may attract [citation needed] type comments :P

Comment: I understand. And thank you for the feedback. It's hard to tell sometimes when a quote should be included vs just alluded to, e.g, Hagrid's claim in book 1 that Gringotts is the 2nd most secure place in the wizarding world behind Hogwarts. Is it ok that I just mentioned that claim, instead of quoting it directly?

Comment: Good question =) Obviously takes a bit of judgement, I would say reference the key points in your answer unless the facts are very widely known. So you'd wanna add a quote if the question was: Was Gringotts actually a good place to hide a Horcrux. A: Hagrid says it's the 2nd most secure place. Quote.

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly sure that Levicorpus has been used even prior to that.

> Levicorpus appears in the film of Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix during one of the D.A. meetings, used on Nigel Wolpert - nearly a year before any of the DA leaders should have known about it.
>   ~[HP Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Severus_Snape%27s_copy_of_Advanced_Potion-Making#Behind_the_scenes)

I also recall it being used when James hangs Snape upside down in a flashback; that was  Levicorpus.

> It is unclear when the jinx was invented, since its "vogue" appears to have extended at least as early as the end of his fifth year with James Potter using it, but Snape notes it in his N.E.W.T.-level Potions textbook. 
>   ~[HP Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Levicorpus#Behind_the_scenes)

I would imagine then that assuming that Snape invented the spell may be erroneous; he may have only worked out how to use it silently, as no one else seems proficient enough to do so.

Or he may have invented it, and the verbal version became part of the curriculum (Thus James using that in him, and Harry Sectumsempra must have brought back bad memories).

Either way there is no reason that a verbal and non-verbal version couldn't exist, and of the two the verbal version would be the easiest to perform, especially for a young, less experienced wizard.

Comment: Lupin used *mobilicorpus* on Snape's unconscious body, not *levicorpus*.

Comment: Wikia is wrong. I'm SHOCKED! SHOCKED, I tell you! Harry read that spell in HBP's book and the spell wasn't used in the books prior to that.

Comment: Calm yourself @dvk it's in the movies.

Comment: @Pureferret - they have a Levicorpus movie?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that Hermione used  the Verbal form of the spell in order for Harry to be prepared for the spell. Even if Snape made the spell both of the forms are still possible and it can still be the most powerful in non-verbal form

Answer (score -2):

I think the most logical conclusion is that JK Rowling simply made a mistake. It is clearly a non-verbal only spell.

Sorry to burst that bubble

Comment: Sounds more like a comment than an answer. Unless you can elaborate?