# How are *Wingardium Leviosa* and *Levicorpus* different?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

Lets take the semi-literal-translations

> *Wingardium Leviosa*
>
> Wing + Levitate --> not really sure but whatever
>
> *Levicorpus*
>
> Levitate + body --> body fly

So presumably Levicorpus can be used on bodies only.

But then why does Levicorpus exist? Draco, in the Cursed child, uses Wingardium Leviosa on a body, so why would Levicorpus exist?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/127719/51379

Comment: They are phrased very differently, but I suppose any decent answer to the other question would probably answer this question too. Same potential answers is the definition of a dupe, so I suppose I'll close.

Comment: But..... Draco uses it on Delphi

Comment: It can be cast on someone's clothing and levitate them a short distance, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Levicorpus can only be used on a person and it is a _Jinx_ that hoists a persons body into the air and holds them there by their ankles. It is translated as "Lift Body". Wingardium Leviosa is a _charm_ that works on any object, including clothes, but NOT on human beings directly. It can be translated to mean "Lift up high".